# signing app on my account doesn't work but it works on my colleagues account

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate, apple-id, xcode10.1

when running my Swift iOS app on my macbook pro 2017 i get the error message:

> Device denied launch request

but when i run it on the macbook pro 2015 of my colleague it does work, we use the same repository.

can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: are you signing this app with a Apple developer profile? I'm guessing that your colleague is has Xcode set up with his developer account and therefore the app is signed on his machine, and I assume you either haven't got a developer account set up or you haven't changed the signing profile over from his account (which won't work from your machine) to your own account

Comment: @AngryDuck i use a free developer account, but my colleague does to, i have changed the signing account to my own, i tried to create new certificates and delete the old ones.